# Lost in Nodester Installation

Tags: linux, bash, node.js, nodester

I am trying to install my own version of Nodester.  I have tried on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and now with CentOS.  I am not the most skilled Linux user (~2 months use) so I am at a loss at this point.

The instructions are located at https://github.com/nodester/nodester/wiki/Install-nodester#wiki-a.  They ask you to "export paths (to make npm work)" with the lines necessary to accomplish this.

```
cd ~
echo -e "root = ~/.node_libraries\nmanroot = ~/local/share/man\nbinroot = ~/bin" > ~/.npmrc
echo -e "export PATH=3d9c7cfd35d3628e0aa233dec9ce9a44d2231afcquot;\${PATH}:~/bin3d9c7cfd35d3628e0aa233dec9ce9a44d2231afcquot;;" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

I can accomplish all of this until I get to the `source ~/.bashrc` line.  When I run that, I get the following:

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# source ~/.bashrc
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token ';;'
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 13: 'export PATH=3d9c7cfd35d3628e0aa233dec9ce9a44d2231afcquot;${PATH}:~/bin3d9c7cfd35d3628e0aa233dec9ce9a44d2231afcquot;;
```

I have tried changing the `quot;` to `"` and that didn't help.  I tried changing `quot;` to colons and that didn't help.  I also removed that and it didn't help (I am sure many of you at this point are probably wondering why I would even try those things).  Does anyone have any insight as to what I need to do to get this to run properly?

Comment: Can you find the directories that it's referring to? Their `echo -e "export ...` command is broken, and it's not obvious (to me at least) what it's *supposed* to look like; but if you can find the correct paths to those directories, it'll be easy to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a documentation error than your failing to understand anything.  Created [issue 409](https://github.com/nodester/nodester/issues/409) for it on Github.

In the meantime, going back through the wiki page's history, I found the following which may help.  It certainly looks more reasonable though I won't be able to confirm for some time.

*Export paths (to make npm work):*

```
> cd ~
> echo -e "root = ~/.node_libraries\nmanroot = ~/local/share/man\nbinroot = ~/bin" > ~/.npmrc
> echo -e "export PATH=\"\${PATH}:~/bin\";" >> ~/.bashrc
> source ~/.bashrc
```

From commit [d71e66b4c96f04c13467ede5f6469d6d4dd17059](https://github.com/nodester/nodester/wiki/Install-nodester/d71e66b4c96f04c13467ede5f6469d6d4dd17059)